Facing problem in Keyboard module in Python
I was using keyboard module to track the key presses of the user.
But I found this problem while trying this code:
Code
import keyboard

while True:

    key = keyboard.read_key()

    if key == 'left':
        print('left')

    elif key == 'right':
        print('right')

    elif key == 'up' :
        print('up')

    elif key == 'down' :
        print('down')

    elif key == 'q' :
        print('quit')
        break


Output
left
left
right
right
quit

It feels like it is detecting that I pressed the left arrow and right arrow twice while I just pressed it once.
So what could be the problem ?
Is there any other module that I can try ?

You have your code in a while True loop that runs forever. So as long as you're holding the key down, it will keep printing the keyname. Perhaps you're holding the key down for a little longer and hence it's printing it twice.
Another probability could be that you have two instances of the script running.
I tried your code and got the desired result.

is there any other module that I can use to implement the same as it requires administer permission for MacOS ?

there's pynput

Thanks but I used curses module
